# tkinter entry() not returning string

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have several entry boxes made with tk: Entry()

I need to put what the user enters into a variable, which I do as such (as I have found online):

```py
window = Tk()

#make entry and turn it into stringvar
entry1string = tk.StringVar
entry_1 = Entry(window,textvariable=entry1string)

#retrieve it into a variable
retrieved = entry1string.get()
```

**This gives the following error:**

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How do I get the string/value entered into the entry box by the user into a variable? The code seems to be just how every example I've found is, I don't see why it's giving me that error.

Comment: you are not creating a StringVar instance, as your code misses the parentheses after it. Try: `entry1string = tk.StringVar()`

Comment: Also, your Entry widget will not appear on the screen. Use any of the [geometry managers](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/concepts.html#geometry). I am answering below using `pack()`

Answer (score 1):

Refer here to know about [Entry widgets in Tkinter](https://tkdocs.com/widgets/entry.html).

What you can do is create a button, on which upon clicking, the data entered in the Entry box will be retrieved.

```
...
entry1string = tk.StringVar()
entry_1 = Entry(window,textvariable=entry1string).pack()

def retrieveData():
    #retrieve it into a variable
    retrieved = entry1string.get()
    #print the data
    print(retrieved)
    #Or output the data on the window in a Label :
    Label(window, text=retrieved).pack()

button1 = Button(window, text="PRINT", command=retrieveData).pack()
```

There needs to be a function to call when the button is clicked. you can print the data in the command line or even output on the GUI window, that's your choice.

Read the [documentation](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html) to know more.